# Display delayed on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I wrote a program that shows a `JFrame` containing an information about the machine that runs it (`HOST` and `IP`) and it make `JDBC` connection to display another information.

I have only these two lines in my `main` function:

```
NewFrame nf = new NewFrame(); //Here I make all the needed calculations
nf.setVisible(true);
```

(*NewFrame extends JFrame*)

In the constructor I perform all needed calculations and set them to be shown in the `nf JFrame`.

When I run the program, I see the **border** of the `JFrame` for *0.5-1* seconds before it get filled with the information, although I set it to be visible only after constructing it.

This is what I see for about *1* second: (The inside is my desktop background)

[image: before]

and then I see the information:

[image: after]

Why this happens although I make all the calculations in the constructor?

Comment: Post your code here. Obviously something wrong there.

Comment: It is about 500 lines of code.. is there any specific part when assigning data to `JFrame` that may cause this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you do some blocking call, i.e. database query, in GUI thread synchronously.  You should do such things asynchronously using `SwingWorker`:

```
final JTextField field = new JTextField ();
field.setEditable (false);

JButton button = new JButton(new AbstractAction ("Calculate!") {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        field.setText ("Calculating...");

        new SwingWorker<String, String> ()
        {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(3000L);

                field.setText ("Calculated!");

                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }
});

JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane ().setLayout (new BorderLayout());
frame.getContentPane ().add (button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.getContentPane ().add (field, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack ();
frame.setVisible (true);
```

Comment: no, it's not - it never was, though documented _incorrectly_ (read: it was a documentation bug!) as being such in earlier versions

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you're blocking the event dispatching thread (EDT)

You should avoid running any operation that might block or is time consuming on the EDT. This will prevent the EDT from dispatching repaint events, which are kind of important.

You might like to take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and probably [Swing Worker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

One of the important rules when dealing with Swing and Threads, you must only interact with Swing components from inside the EDT